# magento controller not work

Tags: magento-1.9

my magento custom controller not display on browser .I installed Alan Storm: A Better Magento 404 Page extension for get idea ..I gives following details

```
 Original Path Information /srinathtest/.
Module/Front Name

Module/Front Name: srinathtest.

The Module/Front Name [srinathtest] is claimed by the Magento module Testnewa_Testnewb.
Controller Name

Controller Name: index

The controller name index uses the controller class Testnewa_Testnewb_IndexController, defined in the following file.
/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Testnewa/Testnewb/controllers/IndexController.php
Action Name
Action Name: index
```

here is my files

IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Testnewa_Testnewb_IndexController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
   {
     echo 'test index';
   }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
        <Testnewa_Textnewb>
            <use>standerd</use>
            <args>
                <module>Testnewa_Testnewb</module>
                <frontName>srinathtest</frontName>
            </args>
        </Testnewa_Textnewb>
    </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

url

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/srinathtest/index/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<use>standerd</use>` - I've found a possible error. Please fix it to `standard`.

Comment: tank you very mush  Kirby... is there any   xml Code Snippets for Sublimetext ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't use Sublimetext. Try to use PHPStorm + Magicento plugin. It's not free but these the best tools for Magento development.

Comment: ok thaks again.i will try..